# Fetching only X/HTML links (not images) based on mime type

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, web-scraping

I'm crawling a site using Ruby + OpenURI + Nokogiri. Fetch a page, find all the `a[href]` and (if they're in the same domain and right protocol) follow them to crawl again.

Sometimes there are links to large binaries (e.g. jpeg, exe), and I don't want to crawl those.

I tried using the [HTTP "Accept" header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) to get an error or empty response for the wrong mime types like so:

```
require 'open-uri'
page = open(url, 'Accept'=>'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml')
```

...but OpenURI still downloads binaries sent with another mime type.

Other than looking at file extensions in the url for a *probable* file type, **how can I prevent the download (or detect a conflicting response type) for an arbitrary URL**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send a `HEAD` request first, then check the `Content-type` header of the response and only make the real request if it’s acceptable:

```
ACCEPTABLE_TYPES = %w{text/html application/xhtml+xml application/xml}

uri = URI(url)

type = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  http.head(uri.path).content_type
end

if ACCEPTABLE_TYPES.include? type
  # fetch the url
else
  # do whatever
end
```

This will need an extra request for each page, but I can’t see a way of avoiding it. It also relies on the server sending the same headers for a `HEAD` request as it does for a `GET`, which I think is a reasonable assumption but something to be aware of.

Comment: The HEAD request is the way to go. Even that can be completely wrong if the server isn't able to figure out the file type, or has been instructed to lie, but it's still the best choice.

Comment: This looks workable, but the performance hit is devastating on a slow server, compared to just testing the URL extension. I'll accept it because it's the correct answer, but unfortunately I can't use it. Thanks.